# MySQL SELECT WHERE start >='' and end <='' as DATETIME using Wildcards

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, wildcard, between

I built a site to insert my working hours as datetimes.
There is an Ajax request on .Change() querying depending on an (Input type="text").
Before the query in PHP i create the where clause regarding that input field.

This Input field now might contain values like:

- 2016 (Will return all rows from 2016-01-01 throu 2016-12-31) : OK
- 2016-05 (Will return all rows from 2016-05-01 throu 2016-05-31) : OK
- 2016-05#2017-08 (Will return all rows from 2016-05-01 throu 2017-07-31) : NOK

  - Should return all rows from 2016-05-01 throu 2017-08-31 (+1month)
- 2016-05-04#2017-03-14 (Will return all rows from 2016-05-04 throu 2017-03-13) : NOK

  - Should return all rows from 2016-05-04 throu 2017-03-14 (+1day)

Top results regarding not-commented clause. The commented will result wrong or NULL.

```
$sd = explode("#",$this->prFilter[$pKey]);
if(1 < count($sd)){
  // $this->prArr[$pKey] = " AND t.start LIKE '%".$sd[0]."%' AND t.end LIKE '%".$sd[1]."%'";
  // $this->prArr[$pKey] = " AND t.start >= '{$sd[0]}' AND t.end <= '{$sd[1]}'";
  $this->prArr[$pKey] = " AND t.start >= '{$sd[0]}' AND t.start <= '{$sd[1]}'";
  // $this->prArr[$pKey] = " AND DATE(t.start) BETWEEN CAST('{$sd[0]}%') AND CAST('{$sd[1]}%')";
}
else {
  $this->prArr[$pKey] = " AND t.start LIKE '%".$this->prFilter[$pKey]."%'";
}
```

In future this shall be used by employees, too. So there will be lots of records.
I would like a working MySQL query and not to add too much PHP and reduce time/recourses.

The enitre query:

```
SELECT t.idTime, p.idProject, t.idCustomer, a.idAddress, 
    a.city, t.info, t.status, p.descriptionProject, 
    cu.shortnameCustomer, cu.invoiceAddress, p.nr, t.start, 
    t.end, t.manBreak, t.trip, p.totalBreak, 
    p.inRate, p.outRate, p.startBreak1, p.endBreak1, 
    p.startBreak2, p.endBreak2, DATE_FORMAT(`end`, "%m") AS month,
    DATE_FORMAT(`start`, "%Y-%m-%d") AS startdatum, DATE_FORMAT(`start`, "%H:%i:%s") AS startzeit, 
    DATE_FORMAT(`end`, "%Y-%m-%d") AS enddatum, DATE_FORMAT(`end`, "%H:%i:%s") AS endzeit, 
    TIMEDIFF(`end`, `start`) AS differenz 
    FROM time t 
        LEFT JOIN project p ON (t.idProject=p.idProject) LEFT JOIN address a ON (t.idAddress=a.idAddress) 
        LEFT JOIN customer cu ON (cu.idCustomer=t.idCustomer) 
        WHERE TIMEDIFF(`end`, `start`) IS NOT NULL 
        AND t.idUser=1 AND t.start >= '2016-05-01' AND t.start <= '2016-08-29' 
        ORDER BY start DESC;
```

How do I set WEHRE clause to get all wanted records?

Comment: Which is the question?

Comment: Oh sry: How must i set WHERE clause to get records incl. the cut off month and/or day.

Comment: I am not sure but it seems you may need to also format the `t.start` as `DATE_FORMAT(`t.start`, "%Y-%m-%d")` in the `WHERE` statement as well.

Comment: Adding DATE_FORMAT did not do the trick so still missing a month/day in my results.